# mySQL on DOCKER (with PHP Symfony for MERCURE bundle)

Tags: php, mysql, docker, symfony, mercure

I have a problem with MySQL in Docker, by default Docker uses PostgreSQL, so I have created a MySQL image but when I launch my Dockerfile, I have some errors, in particular — problems with installing PDO.

I tried to change my Dockerfile, my docker-compose.yml (for the logs, user : root and no password) but i have the same problem

```docker
# Utilisez l'image PHP avec Apache et extensions MySQL

FROM php:8.1-apache

# Définir le répertoire de travail

WORKDIR /var/www/

# Copiez les fichiers du projet dans le conteneur

COPY . /var/www/

# Installez les dépendances du système

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libicu-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl pdo_mysql zip gd

# Installez Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Installez Composer
RUN curl -sS https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -

# Installez les dépendances Node.js et NPM
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    gnupg2 \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs

# Installez les dépendances du projet avec Composer
RUN composer install --ignore-platform-req=ext-gd

# Installez les dépendances du projet avec NPM
# RUN npm install
# Activez le module Apache pour les réécritures d'URL
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Exposez le port d'écoute d'Apache
EXPOSE 80

# Démarrez Apache lorsque le conteneur est lancé
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

Error that I have:

> ERROR [php 5/11] RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-png-dir=/usr -- 8.8s ---­
> [php 5/11] RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr: 5.537 Configuring for: 5.537 PHP Api Version: 20210902 5.537 Zend Module Api No: 20210902 5.537 Zend Extension Api No: 420210902 7.326 configure: error: unrecognized options: --with-png-dir, --with-jpeg-dir ------ failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Comment: Would be good to share the actual errors you have

Comment: => ERROR [php  5/11] RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-png-dir=/usr --  8.8s 
------
 > [php  5/11] RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr:
5.537 Configuring for:
5.537 PHP Api Version:         20210902
5.537 Zend Module Api No:      20210902
5.537 Zend Extension Api No:   420210902
7.326 configure: error: unrecognized options: --with-png-dir, --with-jpeg-dir      
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Comment: Can you maybe rather make an edit to your question and add the information you have, so they're decently formatted and whoever else reads the question, can also understand that right from the question without having to browse the comments?

Comment: Cause for this seems to be https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/912 btw

Answer (score 0):

There's been a bit of [change by php](https://github.com/docker-library/php/pull/910#issuecomment-559383597). So you'll have to adjust following the conversation on their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/912).

One way that will work is the following:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

Comment: Thanks for help, my install look ok, but when i launch : symfony var:export --multiline, it find a road : export MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL=http://127.0.0.1:80/.well-known/mercure but when i go on, this give me a 404 error "site not found"... if anyone have a repo with an installation of mercure of symfony or can help... thanks

Comment: that seems like a different question imho